# Growing my Clojure Tree

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, lisp

I am hoping someone can help, so I'm taking the leap from OOP to Functional programming and it's a bit daunting! I am trying to write a function that will return to me the total sum of numbers in a sub-tree, but I only want to return the sub-tree which is the greater value.  If that makes sense?  I have written a function that returns the total trees maxsum but want to extend

For example:

```
         []
         |
    ---------
    |        |
    []      []    
   / \      /\
  1   []   3  []    <--biggest sub-tree
      /\      /\
     3  2    8  8

(defn is-tree [tr]
  (and (seq? tr) (not (empty? tr))))

(defn tree-total [tree]
  (cond
    (number? tree) tree

    (is-tree tree)
    (+ (tree-total (first tree))
      (tree-total (rest tree)))

    :else 0
    ))
```

This is as far as I have came, which gives me a total of the whole thing, but I cannot implement it to only do the math on the sub-tree...  Can anyone help me out?

I half had a solution but it didn't get me anywhere which was this...

```
(let [l-s-tree (myhelperfunc? (first tree))
      r-s-tree (myhelperfunc? (last tree))

      lt (tree-sum (first tree))
      rt (tree-sum (last tree))

      both (+ lt rt)]
```

But I couldn't implement this into my current function, I'm totally at a loss as to extend it. Can anyone help a hand?

Comment: Could you try to explain again what you want to do for nodes that are not leaves? You want to for each child subtree add all the numbers, then take the maximum of those sums?

Comment: Sorry i should have updated my diagram. For nodes that are not leaves i can just ignore them.  But yea i would like to for all subtrees take in all numbers and only return the total of a subtree with the highest maximum

Comment: I think your problem is possibly lack of clarity regarding your definition of a sub-tree. For example, you could define a depth value and only consider sub-trees below that depth. This would make modifying what you have done fairly easy as you would only start recursively adding from that depth. Alternatively, you could define your sub-trees of interest as levels above the leaf nodes. All depends on what you need

Comment: Is that "biggest sub tree" the node with the maximum sum of its children, with the condition that all of its children must be leaves?

Answer (score 1):

Recursive functions over trees are always a bit of a bother, especially when you're trying to test them out on the REPL. Here's my attempt:

```
(defn max-subtree-sum [x]
  (if (coll? x) ;;Is this an internal node?
    (if (every? number? x) 
      ;;If every child is a number, we should sum them.
      (apply + x)
      ;;otherwise recur once for each child and take the max
      (apply max (map max-subtree-sum x)))
     x))

(max-subtree-sum [[1 [3 2]] [3 [8 8]]])
;; => 16
(max-subtree-sum '((1 (3 24)) (3 (8 8))));; Or with lists
;; => 27
```

I used `coll?` to check for tree-ness because in your diagram it looked like your internal nodes were vectors, and as it turns out those are not `seq?` I've just assumed that anything that isn't a collection is a number - if you have a more mixed-data tree you should be able to handle that by replacing the outer `if` with a `cond` and a final `:else 0` clause like in your attempt.

The major addition here is looking at the children of internal nodes before deciding what to do with them. If they're all numbers then we're making a sum. If they're not then we're an entirely internal node and need to take the `max` instead. You can do both using `apply` (basically, `(apply f [x y z])` is `(f x y z)` - it plumbs collections into functions as individual arguments), once we've used `map` to recursively get the `max-subtree-sum`s of subtree children.